# Renaming .txt files in bulk

Tags: batch-file

I downloaded about 34000 books in .txt format from Project Gutenberg. Now I want to rename all of them by its content. For example every text file includes its "Title" and "Author's Name" so I want to rename all the text files on its "Title" and "Author's Name" by some commands.

I created a batch file. It runs but is not renaming the files. This is my code:

```
    @echo off&setlocal
    cd E:\Test
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.txt') do (
    set "nname="
    set "fname=%%~i"
    for /f "usebackqskip=7delims=" %%f in ("%%~i") do if not defined nname    
    set "nname=%%f"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!nname:~0,40!"
    echo rename "!fname!" "!nname!"
    endlocal
    )
```

Comment: Your script does not rename files because it doesn't attempt to (it does not invoke `ren` anywhere, nor `move`). What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks for replying. My question is that i need a script which rename a text file by its content. For example a text file name is 9767.text, this file includes "Author: Ben Johnson". Now i want to replace this file (9767.text) on its Author Name "Ben Johnson" using a script. I have 34000 text file which names are like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as a base

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Change to source folder
    pushd "e:\test" && (

        rem Where the renamed files will be placed to avoid re-rename
        if not exist renamed\ md renamed

        rem For each input file
        for %%f in (*.txt) do (

            rem Retrieve the data from inside the file
            set "author=" & set "title="
            for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%a in ('
                findstr /b "Author: Title:" "%%~ff"
            ') do if not defined %%a set "%%a=%%b"

            rem If the fields have been retrieved then do the rename
            if defined author if defined title (
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!author! - !title!") do (
                    endlocal
                    echo move "%%~ff" "renamed\%%a%%~xf"
                    rem NOTE: operation is only echoed to console
                    rem       if console output seems correct, then
                    rem       remove the echo command
                )
            )

        )
        rem Done. Return to previous active directory
        popd
    )
```

Of course, filesystem has rules about what is allowed in a file name and, not knowing what kind of characters can be found, this code could and probably will fail to rename some files.

Comment: The code is running and creating a folder but the folder is empty.

Comment: @SaqibAlam, Have you readed the `NOTE` text inside the code? Operations are only echoed to console. Have you removed the `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

Your current script will just print the rename commands, not execute them. You should remove `echo` (after checking what it produces) in this line:

```
echo rename "!fname!" "!nname!"
```

Your script also has a few formatting issues. There should be spaces like this:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=7 delims=" %%f in ("%%~i") do
```

And there should be no newline just after:

```
if not defined nname
```

Comment: Giving this error "E:\Test>fixfile
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found."

Comment: @SaqibAlam I was just pointing out the obvious mistakes in the script. I cannot guarantee it does what you intended since I cannot find any relation between your description and the code your provided (more than _batch_ and _rename_).